# Unity XML Documentation Comments how to customise auto-generate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, xml-comments

In Unity Monodevelop C#, how do I add a "comment" line top & bottom, so that it auto-generates as part of the XML documentation auto-completion?
Currently, when /// is pressed above the class/method/etc, it auto-generates this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
```

I would like to add surrounding comment lines, top & bottom like this to the auto-completion:

```
    // ----------------------------------------------- 
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    // ----------------------------------------------- 
    public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
```

and

```
    // -----------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the thing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The thing.</returns>
    // -----------------------------------------------
public int GetThing() {
```

Comment: Use the Unity3d tag for the game engine. Unity refers to Unity Application Block.

Comment: I think your answer lies into the code snippet tool of monodevelop. Check here : http://addcomponent.com/create-use-code-snippets/  . You need to find and edit the snippet that has /// as a shortcut. (I don't use monodevelop so can't test it)